# Trying to have one div slide down from behind another div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have a div with some text that slides down another div with more text when hovered over. I'm currently having difficulty achieving this. If a good solution includes JQuery, could you guys ELI5 (I've never used JQuery before)? The current attempt laid out below has the basis of what I'm looking for. I just want there to be an animation on hover showing the additional text sliding down, instead of it suddenly appearing.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 2em;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px black;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #E7E7EF;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.below {
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.container:hover .below {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="above">
    <p>
      Some text in the above div
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="below">
    <p>
      More text that slides down from under the above div
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `overflow` instead of `display`
https://jsfiddle.net/yb6vct8a/1/

```
.container {
    font-size: 2em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px black;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #E7E7EF;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.8s;
    transition: max-height 0.8s;


}

.below {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Set our transitions up. */
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.8s;
    transition: max-height 0.8s;
}

.container:hover .below {

    max-height: 200px;


}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a bunch! If you don't mind my asking, is using `-moz-` very important? I don't know much about those prefixes, and have an extension that automatically adds `-webkit-`, but not `-moz-`. Should I also be including `-moz-` whenever applicable?

Comment: No, it's not necessary, I use just in case of older webkits that don't read the transition properties very well.

-webkit- (Chrome, Safari, most recent versions of Opera.)
-moz- (Firefox)
-o- (Older versions of Opera)
-ms- (Internet Explorer)